# Android - Bluetooth Buttons... Media Button Intents or Bluetooth Headset API?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

**edit**

It think all this stuff is now well out of date, there have been many changes to this as android has developed. I'll post an answer when I have worked it out  (if noone else has).

I really just want a background app to get first crack at bluetooth messages.

**end of edit**

I have an android app that needs input from the user - I want to use bluetooth headset buttons (actually bluetooth watch/band buttons - but technically the same!).

I have been looking at media button examples, there are many here and elsewhere which all basically say:-

1) Put receiver/intent in manifest
2) Register receiver in main activity
3) Do processing in the receiver class

This isn't working for me (even cutting and pasting sample code), with no errors, but no events being triggered.

However I also found this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.html

Which is a dedicated bluetooth headset api... has it superceded the media button approach? or is it just higher in the food chain? Should this be used instead of the Media Button Event stuff - or are they just different perspectives?

If the media button stuff is the way, I can post my non-working code, but don't want to waste anyones time if its an out of date approach!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For examples of using bluetooth buttons - this is an excellent example...

https://code.google.com/p/media-button-router/

It detects a hit on the headset 'play' button then pops a dialog asking which app to direct the 'play' to - it plays the choices via the headset so one can be selected without viewing the screen.